# I cant to run my script automatically (cron) Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, linux, cron, raspberry-pi2

I need to run my script `time.py` every day.
I execute `crontab -e` and add

```
15 19 * * * pi /usr/bin/python /home/Desktop/miBBDD/time.py
```

So my script should run every day at 19:15, but it doesn't.
If I execute `service cron status` I can see:`active running`and my file has permissions for read and write.

Somebody know what is the problem? (My script work fine)

Comment: Have you checked the cron log ' /var/log/cron'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar issue some time ago. Delete the user part of your crontab file.

```
15 19 * * * /usr/bin/python /home/Desktop/miBBDD/time.py
```

Compare with [this answear](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/278486/crontab-task-not-trigerred/278930#278930).

EDIT: just one more thing: is the path valid? Shouldn't it be `/home/pi/Desktop...`?

Comment: Thank you very very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you edited the crontab with sudo?

Do a quick test: include a line in the crontab (sudo crontab -e)  that calls a test line every minute, for example:

```
* * * * * logger "Is it working?"
```

This line will execute every minute and you should see the result of it at /var/log/syslog. If every minute you see a new line "Is it working?" printed out there it means you are working in the right direction and your line at the crontab should work ( remember sudo ).

Comment: Thank for reply me :)